# cURL in PHP returning null

Tags: php, php-curl

I am trying to query Clash Royale's api to get player and clan information. When I set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => FALSE`, the request works as expected and the response is output into the browser. However when I set `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE`, it returns null.

The following URL is a demo showing the problem:
http://testing123.x10host.com/clashbot/

```
public function getDetails(){
$ch = curl_init();     
$options = array(CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.clashroyale.com/v1/clans/%23PQGLG8VC',
                 CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
                 CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array('Accept: application/json'),
                  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer $JWT'));


curl_setopt_array($ch, $options);

$reponse = curl_exec($ch);
if (curl_errno($ch)) { 
   print curl_error($ch); 
}
curl_close($ch);
var_dump(json_decode($response, true));
}
```

Comment: What are you doing with `$response`? Where is `$result` being set?

Comment: @JasonAller I am trying to assign the api response to the ````$response```` variable. I have changed ````$result```` to ````$response```` but it is still returning null

Comment: You can use Guzzle to query web services, and it will use cURL in the background. Much easier to understand than the low-level inanity that cURL makes you figure out. http://docs.guzzlephp.org/en/stable/

Comment: @JaredFarrish Thanks, I'll take a look at it now.